# What do the different element type entries in the TypeData for dynamic arrays do?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti

The TTypeData field containing RTTI for different data types has three different element type values for a dynamic array:

```
elType: PPTypeInfo;       // nil if type does not require cleanup
elType2: PPTypeInfo;      // independent of cleanup
DynArrElType: PPTypeInfo; // actual element type, even if dynamic array
```

The purpose of `elType` is pretty clear: it's used by `FinalizeArray` in the RTL, and left **nil** if there's nothing to finalize.  But then we have two other elements, `elType2` and `DynArrElType`.  Does anyone know why there are two and what the difference between the two of them is?

Comment: I just check and the `DynArrElType: PPTypeInfo;` field appears commented in Delphi XE and XE2, and in old versions like Delphi 7 - 2007 does not even appear. Which verion of delphi are you using?

Comment: TypInfo.pas uses commenting to describe variable-length data that cannot be declared statically in the record definitions. The fact that it is commented in newer versions and not in older versions meants that it is new data that is present in newer versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB is good to know that, but in the question of Mason, the field does not appear commented, so this can lead to confusion.

Comment: @RRUZ: This is a fairly difficult question, and I'm really only looking for answers from people who know the system in enough detail that they understand stuff like this and won't get confused by it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler, that sounds rude. I hope which you find that kind of people and answers which you are looking here. Sorry for not meet with your high standards. I was thinking in delete my answer after read your comment, but I will keep it, just because can help to some else in the future.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: just because someone may not know the system in detail off the top of their heads should not dissuade them from answering questions.  I myself am well versed in the internal workings of the RTL and VCL, but I have never seen these particular fields used in practice, and it only took a few seconds to search the RTL search code to see that it only makes use of the `elType` field. If you only want answers from people "in the know" then direct your questions to Allen Bauer and other members of the IDE/compiler developer teams directly.

Comment: @Remy: It's not quite as simple as a grep, especially with the "commented fields" after the string.  Take a look at `GetDynArrayElType` in Rtti.pas, for example.  It seems clear that `DynArrElType` was added in D2010 to support the extended RTTI system. I'm trying to figure out what makes it different from `elType2`, which was already there.

Answer (score 2):

Only can answer the question about `elType2` because is the only one which I use in the past, that field is for holding the element type of an array. check this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  TypInfo,
  SysUtils;

type
 TDateArray = array of TDateTime;
Var
  p      : PPTypeInfo;
begin
  try
     p:=TypInfo.GetTypeData(TypeInfo(TDateArray)).elType2;
     Writeln(TypInfo.GetTypeName(p^));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

This will return TDateTime ,which is the type of the elements of the `TDateArray` type.

BTW, the `DynArrElType` field was replaced in the last versions of delphi by `DynUnitName: ShortStringBase`

Comment: Based on the comments, I would have expected `DynArrElType` to contain the element type info, not `elType2`. Also, according to XE2's TypInfo.pas, `DynArraElType` still exists even with `DynUnitName` present.

Comment: BTW, `DynUnitName` has existed since at least D6, and has always followed immeidately after `elType2`.

Comment: Yes.  I skipped a few elements in there because they weren't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `elType2` and `DynArrElType` are not used by the RTL for anything.  The compiler may be emitting those values just as extra metadata, maybe for documentation generators or the like.